# Self-referencing many-to-many relationships in EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0

Trying to define a self-referencing many-to-many relationship:

AppContext.cs:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("user").HasKey(u => u.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Id).HasColumnName("id");

modelBuilder.Entity<UserRelationship>().ToTable("user_relationship").HasKey(us => us.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRelationship>().Property(us => us.Id).HasColumnName("id");
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRelationship>().Property(us => us.SubordinateId).HasColumnName("subordinate_id");
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRelationship>().Property(us => us.SuperiorId).HasColumnName("superior_id");
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRelationship>().HasOne(us => us.Subordinate).WithMany(u => u.SubordinateRelationships).HasForeignKey(us => us.SubordinateId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRelationship>().HasOne(us => us.Superior).WithMany(u => u.SuperiorRelationships).HasForeignKey(us => us.SuperiorId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRelationship>().HasIndex(us => us.SubordinateId);
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRelationship>().HasIndex(us => us.SuperiorId);
```

UserRelationship.cs:

```
public class UserRelationship : DomainObject
{
    private User _subordinate;
    private int _subordinateId;
    private User _superior;
    private int _superiorId;

    public UserRelationship(User subordinate, User superior) {
        _subordinate = subordinate;
        _subordinateId = subordinate.Id;
        _superior = superior;
        _superiorId = superior.Id;
    }

    public User Subordinate { get => _subordinate; }
    public int SubordinateId { get => _subordinateId; }
    public User Superior { get => _superior; }
    public int SuperiorId { get => _superiorId; }

    #region Persistence-related members

    protected UserRelationship() {

    }

    #endregion
}
```

Let's say I add a relationship like this {user.id = '1' and subordinate.id = '2'}

```
user.SubordinateRelationships.Add(new UserRelationship(subordinate, user));
```

So far so good, here I got: user.SubordinateRelationships[0] = {subordinateId = '2', superiorId = '1'}

```
_dbContext.Users.Update(user);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

After saving, the relationship has gone wrong, here I got: user.SubordinateRelationships[0] = {user.id = '1' and subordinate.id = '1'}

User id is the same ad the subordinate id. What I am doing wrong?